# unique clones finding using SeqIO module of biopython

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I am working on Next Generation Sequencing (NGS) analysis of DNA. I am using SeqIO Biopython module to parse the DNA libraries in Fasta format. I want to filter the unique clones (unique records) only. I am using the following python code for this purpose.

```
seen=[]
unique_clones=[]
records=list(SeqIO.parse('DNA_library', 'fasta'))
for record in records:
  if str(record.seq) not in seen:
    seen.append(str(record.seq))
    unique_clones.append(record)
SeqIO.write(unique_clones, 'unique_clones.fasta', 'fasta')
```

one DNA library has around 1 million records, and I have more than 100 libraries to be analyzed. 1 Library is taking more than 2 Hours to be filtered by this code. This code seems very slow to extract unique clones. Is there any other way to filter unique records??

---

**for python coders who don't have any experience in working with bioinformatics**

clones in fasta format has two parameters, ID (>id-number) and record(ATCG) and looks like below:

```
>id-No-1
ATCGGGCTAAATTCGACTGCAGT

>id-No-2
ATCGGGCTAAATTCGACTGCAGT
```

I just want to filter unique clones based on their record and want to print unique clones (id and record).

Please let me know if I am not enough clear in my question or explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your files so I cannot test the actual performance gain you'll get, but here are some things that stick out as slow to me:

- the line `records=list(SeqIO.parse('DNA_library', 'fasta'))` converts the records into a list of records, which may sound inoffensive but becomes costly if you have millions of records. According to the [docs](https://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO), `SeqIO.parse(...)` returns an iterator so you can simply iterate over it directly.
- Use a `set` instead of a `list` when keeping track of seen records. When performing membership checking using `in`, lists must iterate through every element while sets perform the operation in constant time (more info [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)).

With those changes, your code becomes:

```
seen_records = set()
records_to_keep = []

for record in SeqIO.parse('DNA_library', 'fasta'):
  seq = str(record.seq)
  if seq not in seen_records:
    seen_records.add(seq)
    records_to_keep.append(record)

SeqIO.write(records_to_keep, 'unique_clones.fasta', 'fasta')
```

Comment: Thanks @jfaccioni using set rather a list to perform check in function has increased performance many times.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `set` as it was mentioned above because cpython machine in that code check the presence here `if seq not in seen_records:` and then here `seen_records.add(seq)` (sys.stdin). So I would try this:

```
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord

seen_seqs = list()
IDs = list()

for record in SeqIO.parse('DNA_library', 'fasta'):
    if record.seq not in seen_seqs:
        seen_seqs.append(record.seq)
        IDs.append(record.id)

SeqIO.write((SeqRecord(seq, id=ID, name="", description="") for seq, ID in zip(seen_seqs, IDs)),
            'unique_clones.fasta',
            'fasta')
```

If this is still too slow for you, comment about because this is work for Cython as I see it. When you work with big data in python it is recommended to handle them inside its C/C++ packages & not to use python's loops and things like that.